# Sequential Search Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a problem with sequentially searching, this is the exercise:

> You are testing the physical endurance of a type of brick. The test is made to find the max height the brick can fall without breaking from and N stories building. You have k bricks and two cases:
>
> Case 1. When k = 1 the tries begin from the current floor upwards, sequentially, until the brick breaks.
>
> Case 2. For k > 1 one brick is dropped from floor N/2. If it breaks, case 2 is applied again between floors 1 and N/2 -1. If the brick does not break, case 2 is applied again between floors N/2 + 1 and N.

I have a problem with the CASE 1 cause as I don't know how to approach it:

> Initially you call dropBricks(k,1,N); Being k, and N introduced by the User(Keyboard).

```
public static boolean breakingFloor(int floor){
    boolean breaks;
    Random r =new Random();
    int breakingFloor= r.nextInt(floor)+1;
    
    if(floor>=breakingFloor){
        breaks=true;
    }else{
        breaks=false;
    }
    
  return breaks;
}
```

> dropBricks receives k(number of remaining bricks, first (first floor),last (last floor = N)) and the output would be the breakingFloor

```
public static int dropBricks(int k,int first,int last){
    int result=0;
    
    if (k==1){//CASE 1
        //I KNOW THIS CODE IS WRONG, IS JUST O NOT LEAVE IT IN EMPTY
         do{
             dropBricks(k,first,last);
             first++;
         }while(breakingFloor(first));
         System.out.println("Floor brick broke "+floor);
   
    }else{//CASE 2
        if(last-first<=1){
            if(last==first){
                result=first;
                System.out.println("Floor brick broke "+result);
            }else{
                if(breakingFloor(first)){
                    result=first;
                    k--;
                    System.out.println("Floor brick broke "+result);
                }else{
                    result=last;
                    k--;
                    System.out.println("Floor brick broke "+result);
                }
            }
        }else{
            int mid=((first+last)/2);
            if(breakingFloor(mid)){
                result=dropBricks(k-1,first,mid);
                System.out.println("Floor brick broke "+result);
            }else{
                result=dropBricks(k,mid,last);
                System.out.println("Floor brick broke "+result);
            }
        }      
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue - or at least one of them - is that every time you go around this loop...

```
do{
    dropBricks(k,first,last);
    first++;
} while( breakingFloor(first) );
```

... you are choosing a new random floor at which it will break (which happens in the `breakingFloor` method):

```
Random r =new Random();
int breakingFloor= r.nextInt(floor)+1;
```

This will definitely give you very inconsistent behaviour. It may actually work some of the time by a fluke.

You want to choose the floor at which it will break at the start and for it to remain constant.

A sensible way to test your application might be to hard-code a breaking floor to start with and then introduce the randomness later.

Comment: I see you came up with the same idea; while I was still thinking ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your *first* issue is here:

```
int breakingFloor= r.nextInt(floor)+1;
```

That simply doesn't make sense. The floor number on which a brick will break is **not** random.

In other words: you want to assign a random number **once** for that brick. And then your algorithm has to find that number! Your code changes that "breaking floor number" **while** your algorithm tries to find that number. This makes the whole process useless (and of course; "random"; as all kinds of things can happen).

So the first step on your side: step back, and re-think the problem, and what "solving" the problem really asks you to do.

Comment: Correct. The floor number is not *random* but *arbitrary*.